# Cannot send email from EC2 instance on port 587 smtp

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

SMTP Error:

> Could not connect to SMTP host.

this is the error im getting.

I also read - Because of the spam abuse that has historically been sent from people using EC2 instances, virtually ALL popular mail providers block the receipt of email from EC2 instances. The world of email and anti-spam measures is part-technical, part-political. For this reason, AWS offers Amazon Simple Email Service.

AWS works with mail providers to ensure that the nodes used by SES have been whitelisted because we do proper authorization/verification up-front.

In this case, the ability to send email from one server but not AWS is, in all likelihood, due to EC2's IP range being blacklisted by Google.

How its been solved?

One thing, mail works from the terminal like php mail-credential-file.php So i believe the configurations are all perfect and it all working fine in another non AWS server.

Even i put inbond and outbond rules for the ports in aws security group with no luck.

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: and what did AWS say when you asked them?

Comment: Actually i dont have the privilage in my aws account to ask aws support :(
The above are just my findings from google

Comment: I'm confused.. so you're an AWS customer using their services but don't have privileges to ask them about an issue with those services?  Are you an AWS customer?

Comment: Showing us some code sample how you are trying to send out the emails and the detail error you get with any status code would be helpful to give an answer.

Comment: @flauntster Yes im an aws customer, im a standard user, their support is paid service.

Comment: @PSJ 
All working fine in my non aws server. 

<?php
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
// $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
// $mail->Port       = 587;                    
 $mail->Port       = 465;                    
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Username   = "user@domain.com;
    $mail->Password   = "password"; 
 
 ?>

Both ssl and tls worked.. via terminal

Comment: @VivekSathisan Can you update the question with this code block with formatting? This is hard to follow on a comment.

Comment: have you installed sendmail on the EC2 instance?  if not, 'sudo apt-get install sendmail'

Comment: @flauntster Its smtp. so sendmail not required

Comment: *"I also read... virtually ALL popular mail providers block the receipt of email from EC2 instances"*  This *might* have been true at some point in the past, but it certainly does not appear to be the case now.

Answer (score 0):

It works :)

Check the status on the server by:

getsebool httpd_can_sendmail

httpd_can_sendmail --> off

set it to ON by the following command

setsebool httpd_can_sendmail 1

getsebool httpd_can_sendmail

httpd_can_sendmail --> on

Cheers!!!